# GCMRegistrar.register does not work

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am Trying to use GCM on my app, but `GCMRegistrar.register` always returns empty string. Here is my Manifest  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="net.andromedya.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="net.andromeya.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<permission
    android:name="net.andromedya.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<permission
    android:name="net.andromedya.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    <activity
        android:name="net.andromedya.activities.MainActivity"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="net.andromedya.activities.AcBuEkrani"
        android:label="Example App"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIza--------------------------AmmWJmePg" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="net.andromedya.activities" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="net.andromedya.activities.GCMIntentService" />
</application>
```

Here is my broadcast receiver :

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
        WakeLocker.acquire(getActivity());

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "New Message: " + newMessage,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Releasing wake lock
        WakeLocker.release();
    }
};
```

And intent service :

public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

```
private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

public GCMIntentService() {
    super(SENDER_ID);
}

/**
 * Method called on device registered
 **/
@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
    displayMessage(context, "Your device registred with GCM");
    // Log.d("NAME", MainActivity.name);
    ServerUtilities.register(context, "gcm aliko", "gcm aliko@a.com",
            registrationId);
}

/**
 * Method called on device un registred
 * */
@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
    displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));
    ServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId);
}

/**
 * Method called on Receiving a new message
 * */
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

    displayMessage(context, message);
    // notifies user
    generateNotification(context, message);
}

/**
 * Method called on receiving a deleted message
 * */
@Override
protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
    String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);
    displayMessage(context, message);
    // notifies user
    generateNotification(context, message);
}

/**
 * Method called on Error
 * */
@Override
public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
    displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
}

@Override
protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
    // log message
    Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
    displayMessage(context,
            getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error, errorId));
    return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
}

/**
 * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
 */

private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Play default notification sound
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

}
```

}

Here is my logcat : (there is no error or warning about this.)

```
onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
GCM IntentService class: net.andromedya.GCMIntentService
Acquiring wakelock
```

Comment: Have A look here. working code in my many app..
http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/04/google-cloud-messaging-example-in.html

Comment: You should post the rest of your manifest, as well as your broadcast receiver and intent service code.

Comment: @Eran i listed codes as you wish. Manish , i'll check your tutorial this night.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `"com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"` for your broadcast receiver. That broadcast receiver expects the intent service class to be in the main package of your app, which I assume is `net.andromedya`, but your intent service is actually in `net.andromedya.activities`.

You should either move your `GCMIntentService` class to `net.andromedya` or override `GCMBroadcastReceiver` and specify the location of your `GCMIntentService` class.

Other problems in your manifest :

`<uses-permission android:name="net.andromeya.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />`

should be

`<uses-permission android:name="net.andromedya.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />`

and in your broadcast receiver declaration:

`<category android:name="net.andromedya.activities" />`

should be

`<category android:name="net.andromedya" />`

Note that if you are using a new version of Android, GCM may work without those two fixes, but it won't work on older versions.

Comment: Yeap, finally i got connection to Cloud. Thanks @Eran :)) Now i got my own problem about saving it to my php server.

Comment: I have same problem that GCMRegistrar.register wont sometimes communicate with server. so what can i do?

Comment: @Kenji Without seeing your exact code I can't say what the problem is. You should post a new question.

Comment: @Eran I found that problem is because of my API code that used for demo app and my app. it should not same. and I have a new problem that Receiver wont receive anythings. so plz help me on this.

Comment: this is boradcaster:     static void displayMessage(Context context, String message) {
     
     
        Intent intent = new Intent(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);

Answer (score 0):

Simply keep **GCMIntentService** and **BroadcastReceiver** classes in same package. it worked for me.